# While updating table in MYSQL, getting error code: 1644

Tags: mysql

When i run the update query,[error while update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imdq7.png) I'm getting MySQL error code : 1644

```
update building set company_id =10 where id = 101;
```

> SQL Error (1644) updating company_id is not allowed.

Its working fine in local environment. But facing issue in Stage environment. 
Could you guys please help me?

Comment: Most probably you have a database trigger created on `building` table to prevent you update that column. Since 1644 returns for a user defined subroutine.

Comment: Thank you Barbaros Özhan. Yes, building table has trigger. The prevent the update query. Got it

Comment: You're welcome Jose.